# Unable to edit my own profile

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I was unable to login to stackoverflow.com with my usual set of credentials, and the password recovery mechanism stated that my email didn't have an associated account. I found this odd, but decided to simply create a new stackexchange account and start posting again from there until I could find out what was wrong with my original account.

To my surprise when I tried to edit and then save my new account I got the following error at the bottom of the page:

```
Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:

temporary error updating your profile -- please try again!
This email address is already registered. 
If it belongs to you, visit our 
<a href="/users/account-recovery">account recovery</a> 
page to get access to this account.
```

What's going on here? Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 2):

You had an older account with a different set of credentials, but the same email.

I merged them, so you should be good to go now.